# Why below code gives me different output than expected?

Tags: c, scanf, printf

Below code gives me:

```
3276560 January
3276560 February
3276560 March
3276560 April
3276560 May
3276560 June
3276560 July
3276560 August
3276560 September
3276560 October
3276560 November
3276560 December
```

But I expected

```
1 January
2 February
3 March
4 April
5 May
6 June
7 July
8 August
9 September
10 October
11 November
12 December
```

Where is my mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

int i;
char a[10], b[10];
char *ptrMonths[] ={"January","February","Mach","April","May","June", "July","August","September","October","November","December"};
FILE *ptrToMonthFile;
ptrToMonthFile=fopen("Monthsrr.txt", "w");

for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    fprintf(ptrToMonthFile, "%d %s\n", i+1, ptrMonths[i]);
}

fclose(ptrToMonthFile);

ptrToMonthFile=fopen("Monthsrr.txt", "r");

for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{       
    fscanf(ptrToMonthFile,"%d %s\n", a, b);
    fprintf(stdout, "%d %s\n", a, b);
}

fclose(ptrToMonthFile);

getch();
}
```

Comment: a isn't an int. Did you mean to write i in your last fprintf?

Comment: yes I wanted to show i but I stored it in a char array. How can I show it as integer?

Comment: Read a into an integer variable using &var in the fscanf. If you want it as a string read as %s not as %d

Answer (score 2):

Several problems:

Type for `a` needs to be an `int`, because you read to it with `%d`.

```
int a;
char b[10];
```

You need to pass addresses to `fscanf`:

```
fscanf(ptrToMonthFile,"%d %s\n", &a, b);
```

In addition: you should also check return values of all file functions. Any I/O can fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{       
    fscanf(ptrToMonthFile,"%s %s\n", a, b);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s %s\n", a, b);
}
```

I changed %d's to %s 's it worked now.

Comment: Your way does work, but you could save yourself some space by using an `int` to store the month instead of a string

Comment: Yes that's better. I will change like that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 fprintf(stdout, "%d %s\n", i+1, ptrMonths[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

a should be int if you want to read it with %d. If you want to read it as string then use %s instead.